# bit masks on SQLite

Tags: sqlite, bitmask

I saw across this site questions similar to this one and the answers were usually not to use `bit masks`. One of the strongest reasons not to do that was that it even won't save `memory` because the `SQL server` wrapped `bit` columns to a single `byte`.
However, to my understanding, there are no bit columns in `SQLite` so there will be some memory waste.

What do you think? To use or not to use?

Comment: Use what? In SQLite you can't at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use them masked in integers. SQLite internally uses `varint` to save space, such that smaller values will use less bytes (from [The SQLite Database File Format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#varint))